# When are two Datetime variables equal?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I try to compare Datetime.Now with a Datetime variable I set, using the Datetime.CompareTo() method. I use a timer to compare these every second and display the result, but as the current time approaches the time I set, the result changes from 1 to -1, but never 0, which means these two are never equal. I'm suspecting the Datetime structure contains milliseconds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As other have mentioned here, the resolution is 100ns.

The easiest approach would be to take your DateTime and subtract DateTime.Now. You then end up with a TimeSpan. If the TimeSpan's TotalSeconds property is 0, the difference between them is less than a second.

Comment: TimeSpan.TotalSeconds is a double so you should check for < 1.0 rather than == 0

Comment: Note also that though the DateTime structure is *precise* to 100ns, the "Now" property is in practice only *accurate* to about 1/64th of a second. The timer's *precision* need not reflect its *accuracy*.

Comment: @Eric - Thanks for your insight here. I didn't realize this, but it will explain some timing issues before I learned about the Stopwatch class. By the way, why is the Now property made to be less accurate than the Stopwatch in the first place?

Comment: The two tools are for different things. Knowing what time it is right now is different than knowing how many nanoseconds have elapsed between two events. The precision of a clock should be commensurate with its accuracy. You don't have an atomic clock in your computer; even if you synchronize it to time.gov, your computer clock is typically *accurate* to less than 1/64th of a second so it doesn't make any sense for it to be more *precise* than it is *accurate*.

Comment: @Eric - Thanks for your answer. I totally agree it makes sense. I just wondered why they where implemented in different ways. Is it more performant to do it inaccurate like the DateTime way?

Comment: Performance doesn't come into it; it's a matter of hardware. There isn't a clock in your computer that tells you *what time it is* with nanosecond accuracy. There's a clock that measures *how many times the processor has cycled*, but unless you know *what time* the first cycle happened to within nanosecond accuracy, that is useless for telling you *what time it is*.

Comment: Now, suppose you did have such a clock, and you got nanosecond accuracy out of it. **What if there is a thread switch between when you put the time in a variable and when you read the variable?** In that common circumstance, the clock only tells you *what time it used to be*, not *what time it is*. A nanosecond-grade clock is *useless* because *it's accuracy is gated by the frequency at which threads switch*. Which, not coincidentally, is at around the 1/64th of a second scale. In a multithreaded system it does not make any sense to have a clock that is more precise than the quantum.

Comment: @Eric - thanks for all your insightful answers. As usual I feel a lot smarter after reading your answers, and as usual your answers are spot on.

Answer (score 6):

You're suspecting correctly. It goes further than milliseconds though. The maximum resolution is the ["tick"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks.aspx), which is equal to 100 nanoseconds.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct in your suspicion. The DateTime struct smallest unit is the ["Tick"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks.aspx) which is measured in units of 100ns. (One tick is 100ns)

What you more likely want to do is check if everything down to the seconds is equal and you can do that like this by first comparing the [Date](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date.aspx) property and then compare the hour, minute and second properties individually

Answer (score 1):

DateTime comparison is more exact than comparing with seconds. In your scenario, you can define an "error range", e.g. if the gap between two `DateTime` is less than 1 second, they are considered to be the same(in your program).

Answer (score 1):

Try this... (but change the test date, of course)

```
        DateTime d1 = new DateTime(2011, 12, 27, 4, 37, 17);
        DateTime d2 = DateTime.Now;

        if (d1.Subtract(d2).Seconds <= 1)
        {
            //consider these DateTimes equal... continue
        }
```

Comment: Actually, Seconds will be 0 if the difference is exactly one minute, one hour etc. as well. You will have to use TotalSeconds.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to compare Datetime (as well as double) not with exact values but with value ranges, because it is quite unlikely that you have the exact value.

```
    DateTime d1  = new DateTime(2011, 12, 27, 4, 37, 17);
    DateTime d2  = DateTime.Now;

    if ((d2 >= d1) && (d2 <= d1.AddMinutes(1)))
       ....
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    'simulate comparison of two datetimes
    d1 = DateTime.Now
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(250)
    d2 = DateTime.Now

    'see if two dates are within a second of each other
    Dim ts As Double = ((d2 - d1).TotalSeconds)
    If ts < 1 Then
        'equal
        Debug.WriteLine("EQ " & ts.ToString("n4"))
    Else
        Debug.WriteLine("neq " & ts.ToString("n4"))
    End If
```